# Optimize PHP framework loading

Tags: php, optimization, frameworks

I have a custom built application framework written in PHP which I have been tasked to optimize. This framework is a shared codebase which loads MVC "modules" to provide various functionality. Each module is a directory containing multiple PHP classes for controllers and models and PHP files for views.

The entire framework loads for almost all requests, including images and stylesheets. This is because the modules are designed to be self contained packages, and they may contain images, stylesheets, javascripts or other static files within them. Because of this, there is overhead in serving what would normally be a very simple request because the system has to load all the modules just to determine what modules are available from which to pull static files.

The general process for handling any given URI is as follows:

1. All base system classes are included

   A global exception handler and some global variables are set

   A system-wide configuration file is read. (This is a file filled with PHP statements to set config variables)

   A connection to the database is made

   The modules folder is scanned via opendir() and each module is verified to be valid and free of syntax errors, and then included.

   A second configuration file is loaded which sets up configuration for the modules

   A new instance of each module is created (calling it's __construct() method and possibly creating other database connections, performing individual startup routines, etc)

   The URI is examined and passed off to the appropriate module(s)

Steps 1 - 7 will almost always be exactly the same. They will always perform the exact same operations unless new modules are installed or the configuration file is changed. My question is, what could be done to optimize the process? Ideally, I'd like some sort of way of handling multiple requests, similar to the way KeepAlive requests work. All the overhead of initializing all modules seems like a waste just to readfile() a single image or css file, just to have that same overhead again to serve another request.

Is there any way to reduce the overhead of a framework like this? (I don't even know if anyone can help me without studying all the code, this may be a hopeless question)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's generally a bad idea to tie up a dynamic web server thread serving static content. Apache, IIS, Nginx, et. al. already do everything you need to serve up these files. If each static asset is located somewhere within the public docroot and has a unique URL, you shouldn't need to worry about PHP being involved in loading them.

Furthermore, if you can ensure that your cache-related headers (ETag, Last-Modified, etc.) are being generated correctly, and each client should only request each file once. Free caching == win!

Comment: You'll also probably see a substantial performance boost by dropping APC (http://us3.php.net/apc/) or another PHP cache tool into your server environment for those URLs which are purely dynamic. It'll save a lot of filesystem traffic loading and parsing all those source files, esp. if you drop the syntax check in your loader.

Having the web server handle static content is still usually a bigger win performance-wise, though.

Comment: rcoder, I intended to use mod_mem_cache but that messed things up horribly! I posted on serverfault.com about that one.

Comment: APC is a different kind of cache -- it stores the bytecode that results from parsing PHP source files, rather than their output. Unlike memcached-based page or fragment caches, it doesn't require you to explicitly mark content as cacheable; rather, it just speeds up all your PHP by removing loading and parsing from each request cycle.

Comment: rcoder, sorry, forgot to mention I am already using eAccelerator and yes it does provide a nice boost

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason all of the modules need to be loaded for every request? Why not allow controllers to specify which modules they require to be loaded, and only load those which are requested?

Comment: See my response to deceze: the controllers are inside the modules, and the system has to load modules so it can then poll each one asking which modules have content for a given URI.

Comment: As deceze commented on your reply, that's a rather inefficient way of setting up your framework. :/ At the very least, you might consider allowing a configuration file that specifies what *patterns* a given module might be interested in, so that you can cut down your polling of modules to only ones that at least have a remote chance of being "interested".

Answer (score 0):

Why not move step 8 before step 5? Examine the URL first, then load modules based on the results.

Another one:

> each module is verified to be valid and free of syntax errors, and then included.

Are you really syntax checking files before `including()` them? If so, why is this necessary?

Comment: The syntax checks are one thing I've thought of eliminating, or perhaps caching. They really are syntax checked: they are first read in and eval()ed with a return false; before them.

Comment: To answer you and Dav, modules must be loaded to process requests because the method of processing a URI is to ask each module, "Got any content for this URI?" and each module responds with the content for that URI and the part of the page the content goes on.

Comment: That's pretty wasteful indeed (both things). :) You should cache the "got any content" information somewhere, either dynamically or by creating a sort of "profile index" for each module that can be examined without loading the whole thing.

Comment: @deceze, yes, I agree, I may have to rewrite the framework in such a way that the functionality provided by the modules is cacheable